# What is the meaning of "ail" in this dictionary website example?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests, meaning-in-context

What can substitute the word *ail* in the sentence

> Another fact you ail to demonstrate is how the wealthy somehow get rich on the back of the poor

without changing the meaning?

[Quote from [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ail)]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo, *ail* instead of *fail*.

Comment: well, the link: <http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ail> shows that sentence as an example.

Comment: trox, [markdown's](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) treatment of angle-brackets broke your link.  It handles bare URLs ok, if inelegantly.   Anyhow, at http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ail I don't see such a quote.  Perhaps reference.com automatically sourced it from some site with a typo.

Comment: The dictionary editors haven't done their job properly with the entry for 'ail'. There are two example sentences, and in both cases a letter has been dropped from a word, leaving only 'ail' behind. Specifically, the sentences are: "He would probably be in **ail** except that the only real witness against him is also a crook and a liar" [*ail* instead of *jail*]; and
"Another fact you **ail** to demonstrate is how the wealthy somehow get rich on the back of the poor" [*ail* instead of *fail*].

Comment: @jwpat7 - The example sentences are about one screen down from the top of the page, under the heading "Examples from the web for ail".

Comment: @ErikKowal, I see those quotes now; they're definitely ailing.

Comment: I was really confused by those examples. Thanks for the help. @ErikKowal, seems likely that's the case.

Comment: Erik is right. Epic dictionary *fail*.

Comment: @AE - Which we ail — sorry, *all* — bewail.

Comment: @ErikKowal, maybe you can make your comment as an answer?, or should I delete this question? What do you guys think?

Comment: My comment is posted as an answer, as you requested. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionary editors haven't done their job properly with the entry for 'ail'. There are two example sentences, and in both cases a letter has been dropped from a word, leaving only 'ail' behind.

Specifically, the sentences are: "He would probably be in **ail** except that the only real witness against him is also a crook and a liar" [*ail* instead of *jail*]; and "Another fact you **ail** to demonstrate is how the wealthy somehow get rich on the back of the poor" [*ail* instead of *fail*].